# Caching Values of MySQLin Browser

Tags: sql, mysql, web-applications, browser

I am creating a website in which user enters his position(which can only be the ones stored in my database). To make it user friendly, I want to show him the available choices of positions as he types the positions. Is there a way to cache all the values in SQL(around 30 to 40) in browser beforehand, so that user can see them while typing.

Comment: what server-side technology are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can query your data base through PHP and most other server side scripts and call them through ajax.  You can also use pure javascript with the new html5 specs (but they are only supported in webKit browsers at the moment).

If you want to do it without ajax, you can get the values when the user accesses the page and put them in a javascript array.  This way when the computer reads the javascript the custom values are already there.  The problem with this meathod is it will significantly slow your websites response time.

Example: (php/pesudocode)

```
<?php
    $options = $mysql->getOptions();   // This is the pesudo-code bit.

    echo 'options = [';

    foreach ( $opt in $options )
    {
        echo '"' . $opt.name . '"' . ',';
    }

    echo '];"
?>
```

This gives something like

```
options = [ "opt1", "opt2", "opt3", ];
```

which should be read as an array in javascript.  The only problem is the extra comma but you should be able to solve that easy enough. (and firefox didn't even give a warning)

Comment: `json_encode` is your friend for turning php arrays into JS arrays

Comment: `echo "var options = " . json_encode($mysql->getOptions()) . ";\n"` same thing, w/o trailing comma, in 1 line...

Comment: Oh cool.  I've never heard of that one before.  I'll be sure to try it out some time.